# Glue Crawler CSV without headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I'm crawling a CSV data-source in S3. The problem is that these CSV files have no headers and the Glue Crawler is creating a table for each file (creating thousands of files).

How to deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was using **Custom classifiers**:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-classifier.html

For **Classifier type** of CSV files the field **Column headings** has the option **No headings** allows to inform the Crawler that the CSV files have no headers